# 'No main manifest attribute' error with Maven

Tags: java, maven, jar

Here is my POM file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.codetriage.scraper</groupId>
    <artifactId>codetriagescraper</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>codetriagescraper</name>
    <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
    <url>http://www.example.com</url>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.Maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>Maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2.0</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>shade</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <transformers>
                                    <transformer
                implementation="org.apache.Maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                        <mainClass>com.codetriage.scraper.App</mainClass>
                                    </transformer>
                                </transformers>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.8.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.22.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.8.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.7.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

Mvn package is okey, but when i try to `java -jar target/codetriagescraper-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` it returns me "no main manifest attribute, in target/codetriagescraper-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar". I have tried to add different plugins to make jar executable, but they all didn't work. By the way, when i package the project console show only default plugins were compiled.

Comment: You have defined all plugins in pluginManagement. You should move maven-shade-plugin outside..apart from that you should write `maven-shade-plugin` instead of `Maven-shade-plugin`...

Comment: @khmarbaise, I have this "Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-shade-plugin:3.2.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-shade-plugin:jar:3.2.1 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced"

Comment: This is what you haven't written in your post...apart from that you can check this by using: `mvn -U clean verify` on plain command line ...

Comment: @khmarbaise, Well, all the problem was in firewall. I just added proxy to configure.xml and now it's work! Thank you.